# How to delete a specific cookies in UIWebview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cookies

I am creating a `UIWebview`. In UIWebview I have to delete few cookies. How to fin out the cookies file name?

```
-(void)saveHTTPCookies {

NSMutableArray *cookieArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *currentCookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies];

NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in currentCookies) {  

[cookieArray addObject:cookie.name];

NSMutableDictionary *props = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[props setObject:cookie.name forKey:NSHTTPCookieName];    

[props setObject:cookie.value forKey:NSHTTPCookieValue];   

[props setObject:cookie.domain forKey:NSHTTPCookieDomain];    

[props setObject:cookie.path forKey:NSHTTPCookiePath];    

[props setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:cookie.version] forKey:NSHTTPCookieVersion];     

[props setObject:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:2629743] forKey:NSHTTPCookieExpires];

[userDefaults setValue:props forKey:cookie.name];    

[userDefaults synchronize];

}

[userDefaults setValue:cookieArray forKey:@"cookieArray"];

[userDefaults synchronize];

}
```

Any help is appreciate

Answer (score 1):

If you know the url for your custom cookie, below may help you...

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
NSArray *cookies= [cookieStorage cookiesForURL:
                                [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.sample.com"]];  
for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) {
        [cookieStorage deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***Delete cookies specific to domain:***

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
for(cookie in [storage cookies]) {
   if([[cookie domain] rangeOfString:@"domainName or URL"].location != NSNotFound) {

     [storage deleteCookie:cookie];

   }
 }
```

***Delete all cookies:***

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
for (cookie in [storage cookies]) {

  [storage deleteCookie:cookie];

}
```

Comment: i want to delete specific cookies file name.. so how to delete specific file name...

Comment: i can't get you, what you want?

Comment: i want to find out cookies file names bro

Comment: u there?? i want to find out cookies file name.. how to find out cookies file name.. plz guide me

Answer (score 1):

Delete cookies by specific name,
We can use properties of NSHTTPCookieStorage

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie = nil;
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (cookie in [storage cookies]) {
        NSDictionary *cookieProperties = [cookie properties];
        NSString *cookieName = [cookieProperties objectForKey:NSHTTPCookieName];
        if ([cookieName isEqualToString:YOUR_COOKIE_NAME]) {
            [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
        }
    }
```